# The variance of $Z=Y^2 + Y + 2017$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> Find the variance of $Z=Y^2 + Y + 2017$ where X is uniformly
>   distributed over [-1,3] and $Y$ is the distance from $X$ to the
>   nearest endpoint of $[-1, 3]$

I know that $Var(Z)$ = $Var(Y^2 + Y + 2017)$ = $Var(Y^2+Y)$. I defined

$Y=3-X$ when $X<1$ and

$Y=X+1$ when $x>1$.

So $Y$ can be written as $Y= 2 - |1-X|$

I also calculated $f(x) = 1/4$ on $[-1,3]$ and $0$ otherwise. I tried to plug $P=Y^2+Y$ into $Var(P) = E[P^2] - (E[P])^2$ definition but couldn't solve it. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: If you think about it geometrically, you should see that $Y$ is uniformly distributed in $[0, 2]$.  Does that help?

Comment: @BrianTung I couldn't imagine it, could you please be a little more explicit?

Comment: $X$ is uniformly distributed over an interval of length $4$.  $Y$ is the minimum distance of $X$ from an endpoint of that same interval.  It doesn't matter where the interval is located, therefore.  Draw it out.  The situation is symmetric with respect to the interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Repeat the below for $k = 1, \dots, 4$:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y^k]=\int_{-1}^{3}[2-|1-x|)^kf(x)\text{ d}x=\int_{-1}^{1}[2-(1-x)]^k\cdot \dfrac{1}{4}\text{ d}x+\int_{1}^{3}[2-(x-1)]^k\cdot \dfrac{1}{4}\text{ d}x$$
Notice
$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}(Y^2+Y)&=\mathbb{E}[(Y^2+Y)^2]-\left(\mathbb{E}[Y^2+Y] \right)^2 \\&= \mathbb{E}[Y^4]+2\mathbb{E}[Y^3]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]-\left(\mathbb{E}[Y^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y] \right)^2
\end{align}$$